# How can I nest layouts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Account controller which contains actions like "change password", "change email", etc.
Every view will have the same sidebar, which I want to abstract out to additional account layout.

```
 application layout (header, footer)         
              \/
 account layout (sidebar)
              \/
             view
```

Is it possible to do without editing `layouts/application`?

I have tried to create `app/view/layouts/account.html.erb`, and use `yield` inside, but in this case, rails skips `layouts/application` and starts with `layouts/account`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Visit this rails guides link [nested layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts)